# Power at the differential output

Tags: power, oscilloscope, impedance, output, differential

I was measuring the voltage at the intermediate frequency output of this tuner http://superkuh.com/gnuradio/R820T_datasheet-Non_R-20111130_unlocked.pdf using the oscilloscope. The tuner has a differential output with the impedance of 2kOhm/5pF.
Let's say that I measured 5 mV at the positive dif. output. Now I need to somehow calculate the power. According to the equation that P[dBm]=10*log((Vrms^2/|Z|)/10e-3) the resulting power is about -26 dBm. Can I say that the power transferred through the positive differential rail is -26 dBm or not ?
I am not sure whether it's correct because the voltage I measured is referenced to the ground of the oscilloscope and differential lines have floating grounds.
**Another question is:** assuming that positive and negative rails (with same amplitude but inverted phases) are subtracted at the end, the resulting voltage should be two times greater. Thus the power at the subtracted output should be greater by 3 decibels ? Can I make an assumption like that ?

Thank you for your replies

Answer (score 1):

For a resistive load, if the voltage across the load increases by a factor of 2 and the load impedance stays the same, then the power into the load should increase by a factor of 4, or about 6dB.

1. $$ P_1 = \frac {E^2}{R} = \frac {1V^2}{1\Omega} = \text { 1 watt}  $$
2. $$ P_2 = \frac {E^2}{R} = \frac {2V^2}{1\Omega} = \text { 4 watts}  $$
3. $$ dBw = 10log{_{10}} \frac{P_2}{P_1} \approx 6dB $$

Another way of looking at it is that if the voltage across a load doubles, then the current through the load must also double and, since power is the product of current and voltage, the power into the load must quadruple.